# Don't make a blank cell in Excel if condition returns false

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this formula:

```
=IF(Sheet1!C2="x", Sheet1!B2,"")
```

Its function is to match if the cell from `Sheet1` in column `C` is the same as the character `x`; if true then get the value of `Sheet1` in column `B` and if false leave it blank.

Here's the sample data of `Sheet1`:

[image]

And here's the result using the formula:

[image]

But what I wanted is:

[image]

The blank cell happens because

```
=IF(Sheet1!C2="x", Sheet1!B2,"what to replace here to not to add a blank cell")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to retrieve all the samples from *Sheet1* associated with an *"x"* without any intermediate blanks.  So if *Sheet1* is like:

[image]

In *Sheet2*, cell **A1** enter the ***array formula***:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$15,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$C$1:$C$15="x",ROW($B$1:$B$15)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

and copy downward.

[image]

***Array formulas*** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.
If you are willing to add a "helper" column to either *Sheet1* or *Sheet2*, the ugly array formula can be greatly simplified.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, even though the formula is complicated.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want blank cells, when the condition returns False, in this case you can replace blank cells with any meaningful text.

*You may rewrite your formula like this:*

```
=IF(Sheet1!C2="x", Sheet1!B2,"Doesn't Match")
```